# Parsing $(this) to function within setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that requires `$(this)` to be parsed to it. It is located within an `each` loop. This works as expected. The problem comes when I need to access `$(this)` when used in conjunction with `setTimeout()`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/6e937r1b/2/

To simplify and demonstrate my issue I have put together a basic fiddle. You will notice that the text is not output.

```
$("li").each(function(i) {
    /* below example outputs value if i only */
    setTimeout(function() {
        alertThis($(this).text() + i);
    }, 1000 * i);

    /* below example works as you'd expect outputting the text and value of i */
    alertThis($(this).text() + i + ' outside of timeout');
});

function alertThis(text)
{
     alert(text);   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always you need to capture `this` if the scope shifts:

```
$("li").each(function(i) {
  var target = $(this);

  setTimeout(function() {
    alertThis(target.text() + i);
  }, 1000 * i);

  alertThis(target.text() + i + ' outside of timeout');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Not quite sure as to why `$(this)` is not accessible inside of setTimeout but declared as a var it is.

Comment: It's because what `this` represents changes. This isn' Java or C++ where `this` is a rock-solid thing, it flops all over the place in JavaScript, even within something like `forEach`. Here's a rule of thumb: If you're writing code inside a `function()` block, it's not safe to presume `this` won't change. That means everything inside that `setTimeout` function is in a different scope, so you need to capture anything you need prior to defining that.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `this` loses context within `setTimeout()`. Put simply, `this` refers to the global object when inside `setTimeout()` because you've shifted scope. A typical way to handle this is to store the context of `this` by storing it in a variable (usually `that`):

```
var that = $(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function passed to `each` receives a second parameter which is the dom element itself.  You can simply use this instead:

```
$("li").each(function(i, el) {

    setTimeout(function() {
        alertThis($(el).text() + i);
    }, 1000 * i);

    alertThis($(el).text() + i + ' outside of timeout');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6e937r1b/4/